# Silverstripe Filter Search

Tags: full-text-search, silverstripe

I have a News section in my silverstripe site and I want to use the FulltextSeach functionality of Silverstripe:

```
FulltextSearchable::enable();
```

That works fine so far. But I´d like to have only NewsPages in my result. Is there  a way to filter the search so that you get only certin pageType as a result for example?

Thanks in advance,
Chris

Answer (score 0):

This is untested code but I've just had a look the source code of **sapphire/search/FulltextSearchable.php**

in mysite/_config.php you could add:

```
FulltextSearchable::enable(array());
```

which should remove the default searched classes which are SiteTree (all pages) and File

Then you can add an object extension in mysite/_config.php:

```
Object::add_extension('NewsPage', "FulltextSearchable('Title,MenuTitle,Content,MetaTitle,MetaDescription,MetaKeywords')");
```

Below is the comments from within the FulltextSearchable.php file

```
/**
 * Enable the default configuration of MySQL full-text searching on the given data classes.
 * It can be used to limit the searched classes, but not to add your own classes.
 * For this purpose, please use {@link Object::add_extension()} directly:
 * <code>
 * Object::add_extension('MyObject', "FulltextSearchable('MySearchableField,'MyOtherField')");
 * </code>
 * 
 * Caution: This is a wrapper method that should only be used in _config.php,
 * and only be called once in your code.
 * 
 * @param Array $searchableClasses The extension will be applied to all DataObject subclasses
 *  listed here. Default: {@link SiteTree} and {@link File}.
 */
```